# Flask error occurred after deleting and restoring MySQL database

Tags: python, database, flask

I recently deleted the MySQL database for my Flask application, but I had a backup to restore it from. However, after restoring the database from the backup, I encountered an error that was not documented. When I tried to access the application, the screen was blank and displayed the message "error in URL, make sure you type it correctly".

I noticed that the backup did not have the old "localstore" "g", which I think might be causing the issue. I'm not sure what exactly is causing the error, but I suspect it might be related to cookies or cached data.

I received an answer to this problem which suggested deleting browser cookies or using incognito mode. However, I'm not sure if this is the best solution or if there might be a better way to fix the issue.

Can someone provide me with more information on what might be causing the error and the best way to fix it? I would appreciate any help or guidance on this issue.

Comment: updated quest .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER:

```
delete browser cookies.
```

or use incognito mode

This error was not documented, the only thing it showed was a blank screen saying "error in url make sure you type it correctly"